# Return a function object with arguments partially filled

Tags: r, functional-programming

I want to define an R function that uses an existing function, with some arguments filled in. For instance, suppose I want to define a function `meanNA` as follows:

```
meanNA <- mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

The idea is that when I call `meanNA(x, trim = 0)` I will call `mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = TRUE)`. Is this even possible in R? If so, what's the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take your example, we can write:

```
meanNA <- function (...) mean(..., na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Example**

```
x <- c(1:4, NA)
meanNA(x)
# [1] 2.5
```